# VB.net, How to Combine or Joining Nearest Similar Items in List of String

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, linq

How to Combine or Joining nearest items are Similar for example

```
 Dim _lstOfFontsList As New List(Of String)
  From {"Arial", "Arial", "Arial", "GEORGIA", "Arial", 
        "Arial", "GEORGIA", "GEORGIA",
        "ABOlD", "ABOlD", "Arial"}
```

`_lstOfFontsList`  has 11 values itself, here 0,1,2 items are similar and 5,6 and 7,8 and 9,10 items are similar here i want to group the similar items so tried to groupby funtion like below

```
Dim Cntdd = _lstOfFontsList.GroupBy(Function(S) S).ToDictionary
                 (Function(a) a.Key, Function(a) a.Count)
```

but output is like  below

```
   [Arial, 6]
   [GEORGIA, 3]
   [ABOlD, 2]
```

but expected output is

```
Arial = 3
Georgia =1
Arial=2
Georgia=2 
Abold=2
Arial=1
```

how to combine or group or join nearest (Next) similar items in list of string

Update :
  i am trying to Loop condition for getting above values but the expected result won't coming here is the code

```
        Dim _fntCnt% = 0
        Dim _finalItms As New List(Of String)
        Dim _finalFntName$ = ""
        Dim LASTITEMS As New List(Of String)

        For i = 0 To _lstOfFontsList.Count - 1
            If i = 0 Then
                _fntCnt += 1
                _finalItms.Add(_lstOfFontsList(i) & "->" & _fntCnt)
                _finalFntName$ = _lstOfFontsList(i)
            End If

            Trace.WriteLine(i)
            If i <> _lstOfFontsList.Count - 1 Then
                If _lstOfFontsList(i) = _lstOfFontsList(i + 1) Then
                    _fntCnt += 1
                    _finalItms.Add(_lstOfFontsList(i) & "->" & _fntCnt)
                Else
                    For Each _itmm In _finalItms
                        LASTITEMS.Add(_itmm & " " & _finalFntName.Count)
                    Next
                    _finalItms.Clear()
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

please can anybody help

Comment: You've already asked this question. If you needed to add more information then you should have added more information to that, not created a new question.

Comment: You need to use a loop. A LINQ grouping won't work because there's nothing in each value to say whether it is adjacent to an equal value so you can't group by such criteria. It's a simple case of looping and comparing.  You don't need a magic solution.

Comment: i deleted those questions here because of lack of explanation sir please excuse ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there must be simpler solutions, but this shows the working behind the idea too. As JM said you need a loop and a check to see if the item has more to come. You can't use a dictionary in this case as you need unique values, so we must use a list (of pair).

Hope this makes sense and helps!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim _lstOfFontsList As New List(Of String) _
    From {"Arial", "Arial", "Arial", "GEORGIA", "Arial",
          "Arial", "GEORGIA", "GEORGIA",
          "ABOlD", "ABOlD", "Arial"}

    Dim Output As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))
    Dim Count As Integer = 1
    For i = 0 To _lstOfFontsList.Count - 1
        Dim Itm As String = _lstOfFontsList(i)

        'Erro trap as the last i will error as there is no next item at the end of the list
        Dim Nxt_Itm As String = Nothing
        If i + 1 < _lstOfFontsList.Count Then Nxt_Itm = _lstOfFontsList(i + 1)

        If Itm = Nxt_Itm Then
            'Same as next - so we +1 to the count
            Count += 1
        Else
            'Not same, so we need to add to the collection and reset the count to 1
            Output.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)(Itm, Count))
            Count = 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each pair In Output
        Debug.WriteLine(pair.Key & " | " & pair.Value)
        'Will write "Arial | 3" for example...
    Next

End Sub
```

Hth 
Chicken

Comment: awesome help at this time thank you so much, working fine